# Uncaught SweetAlert: Unexpected 2nd argument?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I have a problem with sweetalert, I would like to show the confirm box alert on button click but it's not working

This is my JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-confirm]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //cancel default action

//Recuperate href value
var href = $(this).attr('href');


var message = $(this).data('confirm');

//pop up
swal({
    title: "Are you sure ??",
    text: message, 
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
    confirmButtonText: "confirm",
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55"},

function(isConfirm){
    if(isConfirm) {
    //if user clicks on "confirm",
    //redirect user on delete page

    window.location.href = href;
    }
});
});
});
```

HTML:

```html
<a data-confirm='Are you sure you want to delete this post ?' 
href="deletePost.php?id=<?= $Post->id ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash">
</i> Delete</a>
```

All required files are imported.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The code you are using is from prior the latest version 2. Please read up on [Upgrading from 1.X.](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#upgrading-from-1x)

You should use [promise](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises) to keep track of user interaction.

**Updated code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-confirm]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //cancel default action

        //Recuperate href value
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var message = $(this).data('confirm');

        //pop up
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure ??",
            text: message, 
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
          if (willDelete) {
            swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
              icon: "success",
            });
            window.location.href = href;
          } else {
            swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
          }
        });
    });
});
```

**Notes**

- type have been replaced with icon option.
- Replaced showCancelButton, CancelbuttonText, confirmButtonText and confirmButtonColor with only buttons.
- dangerMode: true to make the confirm button red.